# 3-phase weld detection circuit

Tags: voltage, current, ac, relay, contactor

I have heard this concept of a relay weld detection circuit, which is used to detect if the relay contacts are welded are not.

In the EV charge controller that I am planning to design now, there is a requirement to detect if any one of the 4-poles of the 4-pole relay is welded.

From a block diagram perspective that I have, there are 3 phase inputs + neutral that go into the weld detection block. And only one GPIO comes out of a block which gives is given to the MCU. The output is a digital output.

I thought of giving all three phases and neutral to an OR-Circuit. But the challenge there was, when I give the three-phase and neutral inputs to an OR-gate, with the frequency of the phases also impacting, I may always get an output even if one of the phase inputs is still not welded.

Also, there needs to be isolation in this weld detection block. As the input is the 3-phase mains and the output is a low-voltage digital MCU output.

Can someone help me with some sample circuits so that I can detect this condition?

P.S.: My first was, if I am using a 4-pole relay, there cannot be a failure with just one pole, right? If the contacts are getting welded, then the probability of having all 4 contacts welded is higher that just having one pole contact welded. Am I correct? So, why plan to have a 4-pole weld detection?

Comment: `there cannot be a failure with just one pole, right?` Wrong. In particular, with a symmetric load, there isn't necessarily a high current in the neutral conductor. At the instant of switching, I'd expect at least one phase current to be relatively low

Comment: @greybeard, thank you for clarifying the question. Could you write an answer if you have a suggestion, please?

Comment: See also: [How to detect welded contacts of a redundant relay? (for reliable high-current e-Stop)](/q/624007)

Comment: Interesting to see this question and another [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/677833/330261), about a half-day ago, so similar.

Comment: (While I may feel fit to argue the logic part, I'd be out of my turf with contact welding and established handling thereof. I'm not even sure if the SF in *SF relay* is for [Safety](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_relay).)